# How do I use local auth and bar code scanner in the same flutter project?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, barcode-scanner, android-biometric, localauthentication

I building a flutter app that scans bar codes and also uses biometric auth in it. The problem is for package local_auth

MainActivity.kt should be like

```
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity;

  public class MainActivity extends FlutterFragmentActivity {
      // ...
  }
```

but for scaning bar codes MainActivity.kt should be like

```
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
}
```

else it don't work. How do I use them both in the same project?

Comment: please help @CopsOnRoad

Comment: @mahmoud-salah-eldin  @ 
Mahmoud Salah Eldin
 please help

Comment: you can direlty remove your class and past given import and class name.. public class MainActivity extends FlutterFragmentActivity {

Comment: local_auth inherited from FlutterActivity() so you can use FlutterFragmentActivity it has both functionality.

Comment: but it's not working, i tried...@amit.flutter

Answer (score 0):

Currently you have to replace `FlutterActivity` with `FlutterFragmentActivity` yourself in `FlutterBarcodeScannerPlugin.java` ([like this](https://github.com/TylerByte666/flutter_barcode_scanner/commit/93c00301b5bae8d400795d123bd28e987112b785)).

So you would want to use a fork of the `flutter_barcode_scanner` plugin where `FlutterFragmentActivity` is used or you use some other barcode scanner plugin.