# How do I use multiple main activities in flutter?

Tags: flutter, kotlin, dart, barcode-scanner, localauthentication

I am building a flutter app which has these two plugins 1) local_auth 2) flutter_bar_code and they both use different main activities , for local auth the MainActivity.kt is like

```
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity

class MainActivity: FlutterFragmentActivity() {
      
  }
```

and for flutter bar code scanner the MainActivity.tk is like

```
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Flutter has a single MainActivity file. if you  want to add more screen then please read doc and blogs here is one for you: [Add Multiple screen](https://proandroiddev.com/flutter-creating-multi-page-application-with-navigation-ef9f4a72d181)

Comment: but bro there's nothing about Main activity in the blog. please help bro. This is the actual question [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73231495/19560313)  @amit.flutter

Comment: okay you can remove existing code : import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity

Comment: and add new import : import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity

Comment: then change class also : class MainActivity: FlutterFragmentActivity() {

Comment: it will work same

Comment: local_auth inherited from FlutterActivity() so you can use FlutterFragmentActivity it has both functionality.

Comment: i tried bro, its giving this error : Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method scanBarcode on channel flutter_barcode_scanner).  @amit.flutter
  and the only way to solve it is falling back to flutteractivity not Fluttrerfragmentactivity....

Answer (score 0):

See this post regarding multiple Android Activity entiry points using `@pragma('vm:entry-point')`

https://medium.com/@vad.pinchuk/multiple-entry-android-application-with-flutter-or-alternative-ways-to-restrict-access-to-1260e097ef9f